# Не работает установщик laravel в linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel

Сама ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/root/.config/composer/vendor/bin/../laravel/installer/laravel): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel on line 120
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/root/.config/composer/vendor/bin/../laravel/installer/laravel' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /root/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel on line 120
```

120 строчка laravel:

```
include __DIR__ . '/..'.'/laravel/installer/laravel';
```

Comment: А как устанавливаешь-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена при помощи перехода на другой хостинг.
А именно REG.RU